# As a ssh client, putty works but git bash doesn't work

Tags: ssh, putty, msysgit, git-bash

Environments

- Host OS: Win 10 x64(x.x.x.141)
- Hyper-v OS: CentOS 7 x64(ssh server x.x.x.142)
- Putty version:0.67
- Git bash version(git for windows): v2.11.0.windows.1

I try to use Git bash as a SSH client. When I connect to CentOS from localhost. Those putty, Git-bash are work either. After configured port forwarding, only putty works outside from the network.

This is the log from Git bash and I didn't touch anything.

```
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to x.x.x.90 port x: Software caused connection abort
```

It seems successfully exchange algorithms each other after established connection. I don't know What goes wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Is it installed? On what OS it suppose to run? If on Windows, why should we care about VM?

Comment: @Hex Oh you saw already when I am editing my question. I know you thought that my question doesn't show a lot information to ask. It was a click miss.